# OpenCV absdiff equivalent from c++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, opencv3.0

Here's a sample from C++:

```
cv::absdiff(input,cv::Scalar(target),output);
```

where `target` is `cv::Vec3b [190, 119, 102]`

I tried the following in Python:

```
output = cv2.absdiff(image,  np.array([190, 119, 102]) )
```

This failed:

> Error: Assertion failed (type2 == 6 && (sz2.height == 1 || sz2.height
>   == 4)) in arithm_op, file /tmp/opencv-20180529-55469-97fkx6/opencv-3.4.1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp,
>   line 661

How do I translate this code correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error message very closely.  Not only do you need the type of the NumPy array to be `CV_64F` or floating-point, the height needs to be 1 or 4.  For your specific case, this means that you must supply a 2D NumPy array with a height of 1.  By default, your created array is of type `int32` so make sure you specify the `dtype` to be `np.float`.

Finally, you can just introduce a singleton row to your scalar that will help you do this:

```
output = cv2.absdiff(image, np.array([190, 119, 102], dtype=np.float)[None])
```

This code `np.array([190, 119, 102], dtype=np.float)[None]` creates a normal NumPy array but ensures the precision is floating-point and we introduce a singleton dimension so this becomes a `1 x 3` 2D NumPy array as opposed to a `3,` NumPy array.

As one final thought, you can also just provide a 2D list instead of a 1D one in the NumPy array constructor to achieve the same result. It depends on how you're creating the scalar:

```
output = cv2.absdiff(image, np.array([[190, 119, 102]], dtype=np.float))
```